# Cerrar sesión automáticamente si se cierra la pestaña, ventana del navegador o no hay actividad de sesión

Tags: javascript, ajax

**TEMA 1**

formulo esta pregunta poque no he podido encontrar la manera en hacer funcionar que si el navegador se cierra, la pestaña o simplemente ya no hay actividad en mi pagina, entonces se cierre la sesion actualizando el estado en la bd.

he intentado cerrar la sesion usando beforeunload, pero solo he logrado que aparezca la alerta, incluso asi me desplace por un cualquier otra pagina de mi web.

tengo un metodo que me destruye la seccion y me habilita el usuario para una nueva, pero cuando se cierra el navegador no se actualiza mi bd, entonces no se como lo puedo hacer usando ajax, jquery 3.

**TEMA 2**

tambien quiero inplementar este script de sierre automatico y que prolonga la sesion, pero se me ejecuta todo el tiempo, incluso si estoy en la pagina del login.(si ya se ha cerrado la sesion.)

```
function confirmarCierre() {
    //le doy un tiempo a la función cerrar sesion para que el usuario tenga un tiempo para confirmar, sino lo hizo en el tiempo se cerrara la sesion automaticamente
    var cerrar = setTimeout(cerrarSesion,5000);//5 segs de prueba
    alertify.confirm(
        'Cierre de Sesión',
        'Su Sesión Expirara, presione OK para prolongar la Sesión 60 segundos',
        function(){
            //si presiona OK
            clearTimeout(cerrar); //elimino el tiempo a la funcion cerrarSesion
            clearTimeout(temp); //elimino el tiempo a la funcion confirmarCierre
            temp = setTimeout(confirmarCierre, 5000); //y aca le doy un nuevo tiempo a la función confirmarCierre (5 segs)
            alertify.success('Su sesión ha sido prolongada 60 segundos');
        },
        function(){

            cerrarSesion(); //si presiono Cancel, pues ejecuta la función cerrarSesion y posteriormente la cierra.
        }
    );
}

function cerrarSesion() {
    //window.location = "/logout";
    window.location.href= "salir"

}

// se llamará a la función que confirmar Cierre después de 10 segundos
var temp = setTimeout(confirmarCierre, 10000);

// hacemos que al pulsar en los botones de Alertify no se propaguen los eventos
$("body").on("click", ".ajs-button", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});

// cuando se detecte actividad en cualquier parte de la app
$( document ).on('click keyup keypress keydown blur change', function(e) {
    // borrar el temporizador de la funcion confirmarCierre
    clearTimeout(temp);
    // y volver a iniciarlo con 10segs
    temp = setTimeout(confirmarCierre,10000);
    console.log('actividad detectada');
})
```

Comment: Hola amigo, conseguiste la solución?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

MI RESPUESTA

Esta es la lógica que aplique para saber si un usuario está logueado y permanece en mi página.

SOLUCIÓN TEMA 1

cree una tabla en mi bd, donde guarda datos con respecto a logueo de cada usuario, la hora de inicio, y el tiempo actual mientras está logueado, cuando el tiempo actual se detuvo es porque el usuario cerro sesión o el usuario cerró el navegador (através de Ajax actualizo el campo actual), con eso válido que en el próximo login puede iniciar sesión depues de un determinado tiempo, es decir si el tiempo logueo actual es mayor por mucho minutos al actual (hora del servidor) dejo que se logue, sino es mayor es porque es igual, entonces no podría loguearse dos veces con el mismo usuario.

SOLUCIÓN TEMA 2

aquí lo que hice fue preguntar si existía la variable de sesión, es decir cada que se loguea un usuario se crea una variable de sesión.

Entonces simplemente valide que si existía una variable de sesión entonces empezará a ejecutar el script del tiempo, si no existe es porque no se ha logueado ningún usuario.